# How many order by columns allowed in mysql, similarly group by?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I am looking for how many number of columns I can use in "order by" clause, for e.g. I have a column NAME asc, START_DATE asc, SKU_GROUP asc and want to add SKU_NAME asc in order clause. I am currently using 1 group by but for curiosity how many can be used within MySQL?

```
SELECT pop.SUB_ELEMENT, pop.NAME, sub_element.LDESC AS SUB_NAME, DATE_FORMAT(journey_visits.START_DATE, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p' ) AS START_DATE, visit_sku.IS_CHECK,visit_sku.TYPE AS `SKU_TYPE`,brand.LDESC AS `SKU_GROUP`,sku.LDESC AS `SKU_NAME`,sku.SKU AS `MATERIAL` FROM visit_sku 
LEFT JOIN journey_visits  ON journey_visits.VISIT_ID = visit_sku.VISIT_ID 
LEFT JOIN pop ON journey_visits.POP_ID = pop.POPID
LEFT JOIN sub_element ON sub_element.SubElementID=pop.SUB_ELEMENT
LEFT JOIN sku ON visit_sku.SKU_ID = visit_sku.SKU_ID AND visit_sku.SKU_ID = sku.SKU  
LEFT JOIN brand ON sku.brandid = brand.BRANDID
WHERE  DATE(journey_visits.START_DATE)  BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-03'
ORDER BY NAME, START_DATE, SKU_NAME
```

Comment: Your query is not going to push any limits.

Comment: This is explained well here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: Note that `DATE(journey_visits.START_DATE)  BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-03'` cannot use an index, but `journey_visits.START_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-03 23:59:00'` can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit, you can order by or group by all columns in a result set, although the latter would be useless.